# Need help on converting a time to date using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using an input `type="time"` and I want to convert my time with a timestamp of `0`. It mean that I want my date to look like `Thu Jan 01 1970 02:35:00 GMT+0000`.

If I write `let value = moment('02:35','HH:mm').utc()` I get `Mon Oct 31 2016 01:35:00 GMT+0000`. Is there a way to get the time with a timestamp starting at `0`without to specified the `year`the `month`and the `day`?

I specify again that my case is working with a input `type="time"` and that I only get the value in this format `HH:mm`

Here is a [gist](https://gist.run/?id=a3ed08fe8d7d7b1f9501ea8e67f9dd40) to play around.

Answer (score 3):

I may be misunderstanding, but to use Unix time 0 as the base for your time, you can get Unix time then edit the elements of the time you wish to change:

```
let value = moment(0).set({'hour': 2, 'minute': 35}).utc();
```

`moment(0)` will get the start date (Start of Unix time), then `.set({'hour': 2, 'minute': 35})` will allow you to edit the time.

This will return: `Thu Jan 01 1970 02:35:00 GMT+0000`

Comment: Thanks, it could make the trick but the problem is that, if I do like you do, and I'm in a GMT+1 zone, I will get only `01:35` and not `02:35`.

Comment: I realize that dealing with a timestamp when I just need a duration can be complicated. In my case the duration will never longer more than 24H so I think it could be better to store them in a string or number attribute and then have some calculation attribute if I want more sophisticate data based on this duration.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the date relative to January 1st, 1970.

```js
var time = document.getElementById('time-input').value;
var date = moment.utc(time + ' 1/1/1970','HH:mm D/M/YYYY').format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss zZ');

console.log(date); // Thu Jan 01 1970 02:35:00 UTC+00:00
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<input id="time-input" type="time" value="02:35" />
```

Comment: Thanks but again this is to tricky for me I will go for a solution where I store the data I really need without having to do too much calculation just to display/edit/store my duration.